# computing checksum for an input stream

Tags: java, md5, checksum

I need to compute checksum for an inputstream(or a file) to check if the file contents are changed. I have this below code that generates a different value for each execution though I'm using the same stream. Can someone help me to do this right?

```
public class CreateChecksum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test = "Hello world";
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes());
        System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : "    + checkSum(bis));
        System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : "    + checkSum(bis));
    }
    public static String checkSum(InputStream fis){
        String checksum = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            //Using MessageDigest update() method to provide input
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int numOfBytesRead;
            while( (numOfBytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0){
                md.update(buffer, 0, numOfBytesRead);
            }
            byte[] hash = md.digest();
            checksum = new BigInteger(1, hash).toString(16); //don't use this, truncates leading zero
        } catch (Exception ex) {                  
        }
       return checksum;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why do you use the same stream twice? Do you get d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e? In this case you coult reset it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the same stream *object* for both calls - after you've called `checkSum` once, the stream will not have any more data to read, so the second call will be creating a hash of an empty stream. The simplest approach would be to create a new stream each time:

```
String test = "Hello world";
byte[] bytes = test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : " 
    + checkSum(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : " 
    + checkSum(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
```

Note that your exception handling in `checkSum` *really* needs fixing, along with your hex conversion...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code in org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html

Comment: Providing relevant code with explanation on where/how that code would help and/or mentioning where OP has gone wrong in his code here would be more helpful.

Comment: You are right, it even doesnt related to any other code. It is a bug

Answer (score 0):

Changes on a file are relatively easy to monitor, File.lastModified() changes each time a file is changed (and closed). There is even a build-in API to get notified of selected changes to the file system: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

The hashCode of an InputStream is not suitable to detect changes (there is no definition how an InputStream should calculate its hashCode - quite likely its using Object.hashCode, meaning the hashCode doesn't depend on anything but object identity).

Building an MD5 like you try works, but requires reading the entire file every time. Quite a performance killer if the file is large and/or watching for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two related, but different responsibilities.

First you have a `Stream` which provides stuff to be read.  Then you have a checksum on that stream; however, your implementation is a `static` method call, effectively divorcing it from a class, meaning that nobody has the responsibility for maintaining the checksum.

Try reworking your solution like so

```
public ChecksumInputStream implements InputStream {
  private InputStream in;

  public ChecksumInputStream(InputStream source) {
    this.in = source;
  }

  public int read() {
    int value = in.read();
    updateChecksum(value);
    return value;
  }

  // and repeat for all the other read methods.
}
```

Note that now you only do one read, with the checksum calculator decorating the original input stream.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is after you first read the inputstream. The pos has reach the end. The quick way to resolve your issue is

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes());
        System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : "    + checkSum(bis));

**bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes());**

```
    System.out.println("MD5 checksum for file using Java : "    + checkSum(bis));
```